# Render result showing something other than camera view?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, camera, image

I was following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbHqIDLa39I) on how to make an animated creek, but I'm running into problems rendering. As I render the image, the actual scene as seen through my camera is rendering, but when it finishes, it shows something completely different.

Here is an image of the render in progress, 97% rendered (taken on my phone)

[image: Here is an image of the render in progress (97% rendered)]

And here is it when it is finished rendering at 100%
[image: And here is it when it is finished rendering at 100%]

What is happening?

Comment: Are you using specific passes? Show a screenshot of your [render settings](https://imgur.com/a/lRarKaM). Are you using compositing?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. No one else but you knows how you set up your project or your textures or render settings.